# Area in "Derived" part of table

Tags: qgis

when I open "Derived" part in the table, gained by using "Identify features" on a polygon, I see two "Area" types.

One is Cartesian and another is in a EPSG projection.

EPSG projection does not match the one of my project. Is there a way I can change this or control it better?

Comment: Does it match the projection of the layer?

Comment: no,  in layer -source-geometry i see other projection.  (propertie-source-geometry).

Answer (score 1):

It should be the CRS defined for the measurments.

Go to the menu `project / properties` on the `general` tab

[image]